# App.config not found thru command prompt

Tags: c#-4.0, app-config

I've created a Console .Net Application using Visual Studio 2015. App.config is found by Application only when I run the Application thru Visual Studio. If launch it thru command prompt, app.config is not found. Even though both - exe and app.config are in same directory. If I set the path of app.config using OpenExeConfiguration API, app.config is found but the value is not read.

Answer (score 0):

App.config data gets copied to Debug folder with the name of .exe.config. So, when u wish to launch your Exe thru command prompt, make sure you keep your Exe and Exe.config in same folder instead of keeping Exe with App.Config in same folder.